# How to set a read only mode for a share in celerra

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage, celerra

I  need to find out if the  Celerra NAS (NS 700 Model) in my location  allows me  to set a read only mode for a share.

Specifically, this is for the terminated employees folder.  They want to be able to make it read only before backing it up so nothing changes.

I am not able to locate where the permissions are and if it allows me to set this read only mode.

Please guide me on this, it's little urgent.
Thnaks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what type of share you are talking about (CIFS\NFS) and what sort of users are accessing it it's not easy to tell you precisely how to do what you are asking but a quick way to do what you need is to create a read only snapshot of the share and back up what you need from that.

If this is a Windows only environment, and you are talking about a CIFS share then you should be able to use the standard Windows Server Manager MMC to connect to the Celerra's Netbios identity and use that to change the Share permissions to Read only. You can achieve a similar result by using Explorer (or any other Windows utility that enables you to change NTFS permissions) to change permissions to read only across the board. This only applies for Windows only environments where you are using Usermapper - in mixed mode environments this is a bit more involved and of course none of this applies if you are talking about an NFS share.

Comment: I 'm sorry Helvick  for not giving the proper information. The protocol in question is CIFS.From Celerra ,i see a "termemployee" share name, and when i go to the properties under Mount Tab, i see the option which says Read/write ( clicked radio button) and another says only read.If i click on that would it allow me to make it a read only folder ,so that i can take the backup of it?
I am using celerra manager GuI to do this..

Comment: Yes - if you change it from Read\write to Read using the Radio button that should disallow writes to that share. One thing to be careful of is that only makes that share read only - if you want to be 100% certain you should change the NTFS permissions on all the files and subfolders. Taking a Read-Only Snapshot of it would guarantee that you have a fixed copy that can't be changed while you back it up.